# How to hide Appbar and show the customize container widget in scroll flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi im new for flutter atleast 1 week from now , im try to create a UI like this that hide appbar at the same time showing the customize container with bottoms at buttom of the UI plus the fading effect any idea will be appreciated please see the link below to see my idea Thank you

[My_idea_UI](https://gifyu.com/image/Abpx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to hide the `AppBar` I recommend using the [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html).

For that your advanced behavior you will have to learn to use a [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

For the bottom navigation you need to animate it by yourself. You can use the `bottomNavigationBar` of the Scaffold through animations as it is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55035120/14559140) which is quite close of what you need. But with pinned set to false at the `SliverAppBar`. And maybe snap also set to false depending on what you need.

You can also try to animate using a `Positioned` inside a `Stack` or customizing a `CustomMultiChildLayout`, this last one is not easy to implement, so I suggest you going for the easy solutions.

Comment: got it Thanks for the idea bro